# How to manipulate SQL Azure database through pure REST calls

Tags: sql, rest, azure-sql-database

I am an iPhone developer. For one of my clients I am supposed to access their database stored in SQL Azure.

I know that there is an Objective C SDK. I have downloaded it and ran the NetFilx example successfully. But of course my client's account is password protected. Also as of now the Objective C SDK seems to provide only read support. But I will need to write to the database too. So I guess that I will have to use REST based calls to update the database.

My problem is that I cannot figure out what will be the URL of the REST services for the SQL Azure Database and how the authentication will work. I tried searching the net but all the examples seems to show how to connect through .Net, Java or PHP (and other supported languages). Nobody seems to talk about pure REST calls.

I can successfully connect to the database using following command:

sqlcmd -UUsername@Server -PPassword -Stcp:server.database.windows.net -dDBName

If such is the connection command, can any of the Gurus out there help me figure out, what should be the URLs to access this DB through pure REST calls and how the authentication will take place.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Pritam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the OData interface to SQL Azure.  Currently, SQL Azure only supports TDS protocal, which will require a library to use.  However, if you put the OData interface in front of SQL Azure, you can call to SQL Azure via REST.

More information 
http://www.odata.org/blog/got-sql-azure-then-youve-got-odata/

Comment: Yes finally we decided that the client must enable OData interface  for the DB then we will be able to read and write through REST. Thanks for the reply.